# Inflection point in this distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

How can one interpret such inflexion points in a distribution like bellow?
The data is the distribution of similarity scores of elements of set A vs elements of set B.

[image]

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190069/672549 The inflection point of a normal density are at $\mu \pm \sigma$. How would you apply that to your histogram, however, where you have four inflection points?

Comment: @Dave The four points of inflection are roughly as marked: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzC6u.png

Comment: My guess is that your distribution may be a mixture of several normal distributions (maybe 2 or 3) with different means and standard deviations.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a 30:70 [mixture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) of $\mathsf{Norm}(5,2)$ and $\mathsf{Norm}(60,7),$ simulated below. Certainly not exactly the same as your histogram, but similar.

```
set.seed(808)
n = 100000
b = rbinom(n, 1, .3)
x = b*rnorm(n, 57, 2)+(1-b)*rnorm(n,60,7)
hist(x, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
 curve(.3*dnorm(x,57,2)+.7*dnorm(x,60,7), 
       add=T, col="red",lwd=2)
```

[image]

---

Addendum: This seems a little closer and has more inflection
points:

```
set.seed(808)
n = 100000
b = rbinom(n, 1, .2)
x = b*rnorm(n, 58, 1)+(1-b)*rnorm(n,60,8)
hist(x, prob=T, br=70, col="skyblue2", ylim=c(0,.13))
 curve(.2*dnorm(x,58,1)+.8*dnorm(x,60,8), 
       add=T, col="red",lwd=2, n=1001)
```

[image]